# IIS Rewrite Rule for path

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7, url-rewrite-module

We need to redirect the URL below using IIS Rewrite module.

```
http://www.old.com.au/kids to http://www.new.com.au/somepath/kids
```

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside the rules node in web config for the site which is bound to www.old.com.au

```
<rule name="Redirect kids to new site" >
    <match url="^kids$"/>   <!-- only redirect kids and not something/kids or kids/something -->
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.new.com.au/somepath/kids" />
</rule>
```